# In Python how can I change my code to remove the double quotation marks in a dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

How to use a string variable to assign values to a dict and remove the double quotation marks of the value?

In python3.6,  I tried to create a dict which the values of it are from some variables

```
text = "string"
number = 1
content = "{'id': '" + str(number) + "', 'text':'"+ text+ "' },"
print(content)

documents = {'documents': []}
documents['documents'].append(content)
print(documents)
```

I need the result like this:`{'documents': [{'id': '1', 'text':'string' },]}`

but the result of my code like this: `{'documents': ["{'id': '1', 'text':'string' },"]}`

How can I remove the double quotation marks in the value?

Answer (score 1):

Define your `content` as a dict:

```
text = "string"
number = 1
content = {'id': str(number), 'text': text }
print(content)

documents = {'documents': []}
documents['documents'].append(content)
print(documents)
```

Comment: thank you so much, I use 'eval' to convert 'content' to Json. but in the result, the double quotation marks were replaced by double brackets. how can I assign the value into the dict with no extra symbol?

Comment: How do you use `eval`?

Comment: like this: import json  json_string = eval(content)